# Indicar valor en gráfica de barras a partir de dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, dataframe, text

he visto varias preguntas similares, he tratado de aplicarlas, pero no he conseguido dar con la respuesta. A ver si me podeis ayudar.

Lo que quiero es indicar el valor al lado de cada barra.

Dejo mi código, seguro que es mejorable...

```
%matplotlib inline
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

datos = pd.read_csv('data/netflixtitles.csv')


datos[(datos.type=='TV Show')&(datos.country=='United States')].listed_in.value_counts().plot(kind='barh',width=0.6,figsize=(5,30))
```

Y dejo una captura de una parte de mi gráfico:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Muchísimas gracias por adelantado! Espero a ver sido claro en la explicación

Answer (score 0):

Como `pandas.DataFrame.plot` retorna una instancia de `matplotlib.axes._subplots.AxesSubplot` solo tienes que asignar una variable a su su salida y luego iterar sobre cada rectángulo (barra), obtener su ancho (valor a anotar) y usar su alto y su posición en le eje `y` para localizar el lugar dónde colocar el texto:

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

# ---------------------------- SOLO PARA REPRODUCIR EL EJEMPLO---------------------------- 
import random
import io

ops = ("TV Show,United States,Drama",
       "TV Show,United States,Romantic",
       "TV Show,United States,Action",
       "TV Show,United States,Comedies",
       "TV Show,United States,Documental",
       "TV Show,United States,Sci-Fi",
       "TV Show,United States,Mysteries",
       "TV Show,United States,Kids",
       "TV Show,United States,Reality"
      )

data = io.StringIO("type,country,listed_in\n" + '\n'.join(random.choices(ops, k=300)))
datos = pd.read_csv(data)
# ---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

axes = (datos[(datos.type=='TV Show') & (datos.country=='United States')]
            .listed_in.value_counts()
            .plot(kind='barh', width=0.6, figsize=(5, 10))
            )

for rect in axes.patches:
    axes.text(
        rect.get_width() + .5,
        rect.get_y() + rect.get_height() / 2 ,
        rect.get_width(),
        fontsize=12
    )

axes.figure.subplots_adjust(right=1.5)
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]